# how to equal two table value in codeigniter get_where/where function

Tags: php, codeigniter

i want to equal two table column value(dynamic) in where clause, my code is like this

```
array('table1.column1' => 'table2.column2')
```

it shows the sql query like this

```
where `table1`.`column1` = 'table2.column2'
```

but i want to like this:

```
where `table1`.`column1` = `table2`.`column2`
```

i just want to change the comma "'" to this "`", please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use simple query $this->db->query('your query here')?

Comment: do you can expose why?

Comment: @Rakesh Sharma : this is static way... that's y, this is the last option.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the third parameter to false, if you want to escape the quotes :

```
->where('table1.column1', 'table2.column2', false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply use string for where condition like

```
$where="table1.column1 = table2.column2";
$this->db->where($where);



$where = "name='Joe' AND status='boss' OR status='active'";

$this->db->where($where);
Reference link:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select
Custom string:
You can write your own clauses manually:
```

Comment: this is custom query bro, this is the last option for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use your strings more explicitly

```
->where(array("'table1'.'column1'" => "'table2'.'column2'"));
```